# Is having multiple class attributes on the tag bad practice?

Tags: html, css, class, attributes

Is having multiple class attributes **on the tag** bad practice? I'm wondering this because I am making a CSS framework which has many classes. I figure it might be best to group certain tags in their own class attribute:

```
<div class="flex inline align-center font-sans-serif">...</div>
```

Instead of the above, I would perhaps try to make it more readable:

```
<div class="flex inline align-center" class="font-sans-serif">...</div>
```

Would this be considered bad practice? Could it be more confusing?

Comment: Yes, it's bad practice because it's not valid HTML.

Comment: The second approach is not standard, so it can works on some browsers, but it's deprecated. The first one, instead, is very common, and modularize the css using many classes (as long as in reasonable number) is a strategy adopted by many frameworks (for example: Bootstrap).

Comment: @Davide Visentin: "Deprecated" implies it was once part of the standard. Except it never was. It's invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The first is more preferable. Using two class attributes is like resetting the first class to the second

```
<div class="flex inline align-center font-sans-serif">...</div>
```

The above is better

Comment: The second is **HTML INVALID**